# pods fail with FailedSync reason and no explanation

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a cluster on google cloud container engine with 6 `n1-standard-1` machine.

I deployed several services and pod on this cluster and sometime they fail with the only reason `FailedSync` and no more explanation, I have no idea why they fail. Virtual machine are not overloaded, only 6% of the CPU is used and less than 1Gi of memory.

Here some events from describe command :

[image: events 1]
[image]

pods filter by `is system object: true` have the same problem, some of them have more than 900 restarts in 4 days...

[image]

I miss maybe something in my kubernetes configuration and I have no idea what...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to find out the issue is just ssh to the node and use `sudo docker logs $CONTAINER_Id` to see what happened to your applications.

You can tell on what nodes your applications are deployed to by `kubectl describe po $PO_NAME` or simply `kubectl get po -o wide`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
I ran `kubectl get nodes` and on 6 nodes 5 are not ready. I ssh on one not ready, no docker container are running and the describe command list several non terminated pods.
I have no idea why these nodes are `Not Ready`...

Comment: Have you tried `kubectl describe node $NODE_NAME` to find possible issues?

Comment: Yes I tried it and I have no events and in the conditions some types are `Unknown` : OutOfDisk, MemoryPressure, DiskPressure, Ready with the same message `Kubelet stopped posting node status.` ans kubelet is indeed not running

Comment: Hey, how about looking at the logs of kubelet? I guess you can find some clues there.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the reason of the node failures. I use a glusterfs volume with the https://eventstore.org/ database and I think the latency make it fails, I saw lot of slow queries in the eventstore logs. I don't really know what happen but since I use a persistent ssd disk in the same region of my cluster I have no issue. 0 restart since several days and nodes work like a charm.

I also isolated this database on a single node.